# Pygame Rendering Text 1 by 1 Causes Lag In Game How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, pygame

when ever I try to display to render this text 1 by 1 it seems to slow my game down and make everything run slow and for some reason it starts the text as well I want it to end when its finished typing the text [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/339185074f0cde73cf6559cb2467e1d3)< as you can see in the video the text keeps playing the game keeps lagging for some reason when ever each of the text is rendered on the screen

```
    def show_text(string):
        WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
        text = ''
        font = pygame.font.Font("Alice.ttf", 30)
        for i in range(len(string)):
            text += string[i]
            text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
            text_rect.center = (700/2, 800/2)
            window.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(100)
```

```
        display_text_animation('Hello World!')
```

heres the full code there all rects execept the Alice.tff < text style

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,self.color,self.rect)

white = (120,120,120)
player1 = player(150,150,50,50,white)
def display_text_animation(string):
    text = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        text += string[i]
        font = pygame.font.Font("Alice.ttf", 30)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, white)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(100)

def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            player1.x += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            player1.x -= 5
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))        
        player1.draw()
        display_text_animation('Hello World!')
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not create the `pygame.font.Font` object in every frame. Creating a font object is very time consuming. Every time the `Font` object is created, the font file ("Alice.ttf") must be read and interpreted. Create the `Font`object before the application loop during initialization.

Furthermore do not animate the text in a loop use the application loop. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to measure the time. Calculate the number of letters to be displayed as a function of time:

```py
font = pygame.font.Font("Alice.ttf", 30)
```

```py
def display_text_animation(string, start_time):
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()  
    letters = (current_time - start_time) // 100 
    text = string[:letters]
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (700/2, 800/2)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
```

```py
def main():
    text = 'Hello World!'
    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()    

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            player1.x += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            player1.x -= 5

        DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))        
        player1.draw()
        display_text_animation(text, start_time)
        pygame.display.update()
```

When ever you want to animate a new text you just have to set `text` and `start_time`. e.g:

```py
text = "New text"
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

---

Minimal typewriter effect example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 150))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (32, 32, 32), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

text = 'Hello World'
text_len = 0
typewriter_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(typewriter_event, 100)
text_surf = None

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == typewriter_event:
            text_len += 1
            if text_len > len(text):
                text_len = 0
            text_surf = None if text_len == 0 else font.render(text[:text_len], True, (255, 255, 128))

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    if text_surf:
        window.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(midleft = window.get_rect().midleft).move(40, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: it still seems to be lagging

Comment: @lillymosling I've changed the answer.

Comment: it works great with no lag but it shows part of the text then renders the other half like it just blits part of the first 3 or 4 words then renders the other half 1 by by 1

Comment: also what do you mean by if I want to animate a new text all I have to do is have the sam ename text = "new text" and add another start_time?

Comment: `text = 'Oh No! he looks Strong'
    text = 'Must Be Careful squeak'
    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()    
    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()` # examplee